# Laravel querybuilder distinct function not working in search

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel

I tried putting `distinct()` in my query but when i get the results in my frontend and in the api, I still get duplicate records. Does anyone know why `distinct` is not working in my code?

My code

```
 $result =  DB::connection('mysql2')
                    ->table('xp_pn_ura_transactions')
                    ->whereRaw(DB::raw("CONCAT(block, ' ', street,' ',project_name,' ', postal_code,'')LIKE '%$request->projectname%' order by STR_TO_DATE(sale_date, '%d-%M-%Y') asc"))
                    ->limit($request->limit)
                    ->distinct()
                    ->get();

 return \Response::json(array(
                //'total_count' => $count,
                'result' => $result,
            ));
```

Front end result
[image]

My response, I only get the first two objects that duplicates

```
{
"id": 228686,
"transtype": "RESI",
"project_name": "WATERFRONT WAVES",
"unitname": "08-06 ",
"block": "760",
"street": "Bedok Reservoir Road  ",
"level": "08",
"stack": "06 ",
"no_of_units": "1",
"area": "147",
"type_of_area": "Strata",
"transacted_price": "1300500",
"nettprice": "-",
"unitprice_psm": "8847",
"unitprice_psf": "822",
"sale_date": "20-JAN-2008",
"contract_date": " ",
"property_type": "Condominium",
"tenure": "99 Yrs From 31/10/2007",
"completion_date": "Uncompleted",
"type_of_sale": "New Sale",
"purchaser_address_indicator": "Private",
"postal_district": "16",
"postal_sector": "47",
"postal_code": "479245",
"planning_region": "East Region",
"planning_area": "Bedok",
"update_time": "2019-12-09 17:14:35"
},
{
"id": 224686,
"transtype": "RESI",
"project_name": "WATERFRONT WAVES",
"unitname": "08-06 ",
"block": "760",
"street": "Bedok Reservoir Road  ",
"level": "08",
"stack": "06 ",
"no_of_units": "1",
"area": "147",
"type_of_area": "Strata",
"transacted_price": "1300500",
"nettprice": "-",
"unitprice_psm": "8847",
"unitprice_psf": "822",
"sale_date": "20-JAN-2008",
"contract_date": " ",
"property_type": "Condominium",
"tenure": "99 Yrs From 31/10/2007",
"completion_date": "Uncompleted",
"type_of_sale": "New Sale",
"purchaser_address_indicator": "Private",
"postal_district": "16",
"postal_sector": "47",
"postal_code": "479245",
"planning_region": "East Region",
"planning_area": "Bedok",
"update_time": "2019-12-09 17:11:57"
}
```

They got different `id` but same records, is there a way to ignore the id and get the other fields?

Comment: Did you try firing raw queries in DB directly and see what you get?

Comment: its the same sir @nicholasnet

Comment: Then the problem is in your query not in Laravel once you fix the query you can simply translate it into Laravel query builder.

Comment: yes the problem is in my querybuidler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the field that you need to `distinct`, or it will `distinct` all the fields that you selected:

So according to your post, the `id` and `updated_time` are not duplicated, you don't need to select it out.

Try something like this:

```php
$result =  DB::connection('mysql2')
                    ->table('xp_pn_ura_transactions')
                    ->whereRaw(DB::raw("CONCAT(block, ' ', street,' ',project_name,' ', postal_code,'')LIKE '%$request->projectname%' order by STR_TO_DATE(sale_date, '%d-%M-%Y') asc"))
                    ->limit($request->limit)
# select the fields which is duplicated.(In your post, select the field without id and updated_time)
                    ->select("transtype",
"project_name",
"unitname",
"block",
"street",
"level",
"stack",
"no_of_units",
"area",
"type_of_area",
"transacted_price",
"nettprice",
"unitprice_psm",
"unitprice_psf",
"sale_date",
"contract_date",
"property_type",
"tenure",
"completion_date",
"type_of_sale",
"purchaser_address_indicator",
"postal_district",
"postal_sector",
"postal_code",
"planning_region",
"planning_area")
                    ->distinct()
                    ->get();
```

if you need to select the fields not duplicated, you can use `groupBy()` instead of `distinct()`

Comment: so I need to put all the fields in `select()` except for the `id` right sir?

Comment: @Vince you need to select the duplicated fields, and I think your `id`, `updated_time` is not duplicated. you don't need to select them out, if you don't need to display them.

Comment: what do you mean? @TsaiKoga? I just dont want duplicates in my results.

Comment: @Vince I means `distinct` method is base on the fields that you selected, if you select the fields not duplicated, like `id` and `updated_time`, it will think those two records are not duplicated, like your post, those two json `228686` and `224686` is not duplicated.

Comment: im a bit confused, i tried `distinct('id,update_time)` I still get duplicates.

Comment: @Vince no, I means don't select these two fields. let me update the answer for you.

Comment: i also tried `distinct(all the fields except id and update)` still duplicates

Comment: ohh i see.. thanks for this @TsaiKoga. Is there any way to do it like `select * except` in querybuilder?

Comment: @Vince for mysql, there is no way. However select the fields you want  instead of all fields can reduce IO cost. It's good performance.